# Creating new SQLite DBs with PDO

Tags: php, database, sqlite, pdo

I want to provide a setup feature in my next project and I'm wondering if it's possible to create a SQLite 3 database from scratch with PDO or I'm just stuck at connecting to existing databases via DSN?

If it isn't possible with PDO is there any way to create a new DB via PHP?

Comment: Why didn't you supply the sqlite file as well?

Comment: I can do that, but I want to know if there is a way to create DB by running SQL statements like CREATE DATABASE, CREATE TABLE and so on.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A new sqlite database is created when you open a connection to one that doesn't exist. You can just check if the file exists, and then if it doesn't, then just create a new database connection and insert the tables.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't knew that. Also, is there a way to specify the database file permissions (chmod) upon creation?

Comment: No, but the default is 666, I think. And so you can change it after you've created it and closed the connection.

The directory where it's created needs to be writable though.