# Why PHP PDO SQLite always creates a new empty database file?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I created connection to database, but I dont know why it always create a new empty database.sql file. When I rename the database file he creates always a new file instead giving me an error.

Here is my code

```
$db = new PDO("sqlite:".__DIR__."/database.sql");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: It is how PDO SQLite works - see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1893799/4930070).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating new SQLite DBs with PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893767/creating-new-sqlite-dbs-with-pdo)

Comment: "When I rename the database file he creates always a new file instead giving me an error." as it should. if you want to check the file exists you can use `file_exists()`

Answer (score 12):

This is the expected behaviour. When SQLite is called, it looks for the filename specified.

```
    $db = new PDO("sqlite:".__DIR__."/database.sql");
```

If the database.sql file is not found, it will attempt to create the file.

As an aside, you might want to change the file extension from .sql to .sqlite for clarity.