# Catch branch doesn't execute

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, try-catch

```
try{
    $db=new PDO("sqlite:".__DIR__."/database.db");
    echo"Connected";
}catch(Exception $e ){
    echo "Unable to connect to the database!";
}
```

If file is found "Connected" shows, but if file doesn't exist `catch` branch doesn't show "Unable to connect to the database!". It creates another file with wrong name and echos "Connected" instead.

Comment: use file_exist.

Comment: _"Can somebody explain me why this is happen"_ - because that's how it works with sqlite - if you try to connect to a non-existing database, then it will _create_ a database file for it in that moment. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1893799/1427878

Comment: @Karmen `file_exists` returns a boolean, I don't think the code you posted in your comment does what you think it does

Comment: @brombeer Your right ...catch the problem but....doesn't work after... when i try a query